# MVVM Creating the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

Can somebody explain to me how exactly to create a ViewModel for the MVVM Pattern.
I tried to understand the the tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx , but I was unable to understand what exactly is happening in the code.

Let's say we want to create a basic application about getting and adding people from and to a local database and displaying them in the View. How should the ViewModel look like and how to create the RelayCommands for it. First why do we set the variables twice: once privately and then again publicaly.

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far. I have one more thing that I don't know to do - how to bind the View to the ViewModel and Vice Versa

Here is the Model:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string name;
    private string surname;
    private string age;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return surname;
        }
        set
        {
            surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }

    public string Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<Student> studentList;
    Student selectedPerson;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //populate some sample data
        studentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
    {
        new Student(){Name="John", Surname="Smith", Age="28"},
        new Student(){Name="Barbara", Surname="Anderson", Age="23"}
    };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList
    {
        get { return studentList; }
    }

    public Student SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            selectedPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _addStudentCommand;
    public ICommand AddStudentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addStudentCommand
                ?? (_addStudentCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    studentList.Add(student);
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

I have found a way to bind the ViewModel to the View using some code for the view in Csharp but the question how to bind the View to the ViewModel is still on my mind. To be more specific how to create a new student using the values a user has entered in the View.

Here is the View's XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMLight.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock"
               Text="Name"
               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="SurnameTextBlock"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Surname"
               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AgeTextBlock"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Text="Age"
               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="SurnameTextBox"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="AgeTextBox"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="StudentListBox"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.Row="4"
             Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTextStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="AddButton"
            Grid.Row="7"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Add"
            Margin="7,7,7,7"
            Command="{Binding AddStudentCommand}"/>        
</Grid>
```

And here is the View's Csharp code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

I have some questions concerning the Binding between the View and The ViewModel:
What are the pros and cons of using this type of binding?
What is the best way of binding if I am going to use a database?

1. Is this how the ViewModel and Model should look like
2. How to create a RelayCommand for adding a student to the ObservableCollection
3. Why do we set things first privately and then again publically [Answered]
4. How to bind the View to the ViewModel and Vice Versa

Comment: your ViewModel would have an `ObservableCollection<Person>` and a couple of commands, such as `AddPersonCommand` and `RemovePersonCommand`. What is your question?

Comment: Have you downloaded the demo project and browsed the code a little? Once I did that, most aspects of MVVM became clear to me very quickly.

Comment: @HighCore My question is how to define those commands

Comment: @Xaser I browsed too. I understood the View and the Model with the INotifyPropertyChange implementation but I still don't understand fully the ViewModel

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov then post the code of what you already tried.

Comment: @HighCore Here are the code snippets and what now, how should the RelayCommands be created and

Comment: Side note: be very careful: you have spelled or passed the wrong value to OnPropertyChanged nearly every time! In general it should be a constant string stating the name of the property.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd thanks for the tip, I'm kind in a rush now so I missed the inverted commas

Comment: @Ernodeweerd or use strongly-typed `Expression`-based `NotifyPropertyChanged()`.

Comment: Also: "SelectedPerson" vs "SelectedStudent"...

Comment: @HighCore - yes but that leads away from the question. (Which still isn't clear.

Comment: `Why do we set things first privately and then again publically` - because public properties need private backing fields. That's just how properties work in C#. You can't store data in a `Property` as such, because in the end a "Property" in C# is just a pair of `methods` (`getXXX()` and `setXXX()`)

Comment: @HighCore You answered my first question while I was typing so the second question is how to create a RelayCommand for adding a person to that ObservableCollection(getting the data from the View).

Comment: `getting the data from the View` - is achieved via DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore As much as I know in this case DataBinding mean Binding a Command to a Button, am I right?

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov, no, I mean binding  UI elements such as `TextBox` to properties in your data object, so that inputting text in these will update your data.

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov you can bind the command to the button and you can bind the Student objects properties to the view. ( sorry said that backwards, you can bind the button to the command and the elements in the UI to the student)

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov I've just started a new blog series "Getting Started With MVVM" that you might find helpful - http://blog.leavey.org/

Comment: @Peregrine Thanks, I will stay tuned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your property setters you should check to see if the new value is equal to the old value, if it is you should return and not fire the PropertyChanged event.

As for your questions:

1. Yes this looks fine.
2. There are a couple of ways to setup your relay commands.  I prefer

   ```
   private RelayCommand<Student> _addStudentCommand;
   public ICommand AddStudentCommand
   {
       get
       {
           return _addStudentCommand
               ?? (_addStudentCommand = new RelayCommand<Student>((student) =>
                   {
                        studentList.Add(student);
                   }));
       }
   }
   ```

another way without passing in a student object

```
private RelayCommand _addStudentCommand;
    public ICommand AddStudentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addStudentCommand
                ?? (_addStudentCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                        Student student = new Student(); 
                        studentList.Add(student);
                    }));
        }
    }
```

1. That is how properties work in .net, You could use automatic properties, but since you need to fire change notification in the setter you have to declare the field that the property will work against.

Also since it looks like you are using mvvm light you should try the code snippets.  They make properties very easy to create.  type mvvvminpc then hit tab twice.  then fill in the highlighted part and hit tab till you are finished.

You can bind the View To the Viewmodel a couple of ways. I know that it is an Antipattern but you could use a locator. The basic idea is to set the viewmodel as the views datacontext.

```
public class Locator
{
   public Viewmodel1 Viewmodel1
    {
       return new Viewmodel1();
    }   
}
```

You then in you app.xaml you add this class

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Locator x:key="VMLocator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in your view in the xaml

```
<Page  DataContext="{Binding Source="{StaticResource VMLocator}" Path=ViewModel1}">

</Page>
```

Comment: and how should the RelayCommand class lock like?
EDIT: I'm not using the MVVM light framework, just the approach that it the framework uses

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov I don't understand RelayCommand and RelayCommand<T> are included in the mvvm light toolkit. The advantage of RelayCommand is that you do not have to create your own implementation of ICommand.

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov You'll see RelayCommand in the code you were browsing or any mvvm framework. You don't need to write your own.

Comment: @bland I added the MVVMLight Framework and yeah the code is there.
NOTE: I never tried to use any framework

Comment: @jfin3204 One more question why can't I access the studentList ObservableCollection using your code snippet, or should I say how can I access it?

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov you should be able to. Make sure that you are accessing the field not the property since you only defined a get and not a set.  -- strike that you should be able to access it by the getter, it is getting towards the end of the day.

Comment: @jfin3204 I'm obviously making a mistake somewhere but I don't know where exactly. I updated the code snippet in the first post, could you take a look and tell me what am I making wrong
NOTE: It tells me this "the non-generic type 'Commands.RelayCommand' cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov where are you creating a new student object.  The RelayCommand that I wrote takes a student as a parameter.  If you want the command to create and add a new student then you need to change the code.  I'll add it to the code above.

Comment: @jfin3204 that fixes the above error but a new one comes after: "'Commands.RelayCommand' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument" What should that mean?

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov That should work. You're using Galasoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand, correct?

Comment: @jfin3204 It's a compile error, I cannot run the app. 
NOTE: The error is almost the same: "Commands.RelayCommand" does not caontain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Comment: @jfin3204 I fixed it but I have no idea how should I bind the view to the view model and vice versa. Can you help me on this one too

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov I updated my answer to include one way of connecting the view and viewmodel.  This is an anti pattern though. I've used it in a few applications and for the most part it works the way that I've wanted.

Comment: @jfin3204 What are the cons for this type of connection between the view and the viewmodel and which is the best for using a database

Comment: @jfin3204 If I try to implement your code the designer gives me a bunch of errors like: "Expected '>'", "Character sequence '{' was not found at this location", "'{' is not a valid name", "White space is missing", "There is a missing equals character". And also in the App.xaml page I don't see in the list any Locator tags. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov I don't really get the question about which is better for database.  In app.xaml you are going to need to import the namespace that your locator class belongs to.Post the first part of your xaml for your page.  I need to see what the markup looks like in order to   figure out why it is giving you errors

Comment: @jfin3204 I have found another way of binding the ViewModel to the View which is by using the code behind the View. "DataContext = new MainViewModel();" Which seems simpler to me but I don't know if there is any difference between your way and the way I did it

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov it is different but it accomplishes the task.