# WPF MVVM Binding Entity Frame Work Results to Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

i am implementing a mvvm model. i have class called Dep_Class in My Model

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace mency.Models
{
    class Dep_class : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string dep_name;

        public string Dep_Name
        {
            get { return dep_name; }
            set
            {
                dep_name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Dep_Name");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public Dep_class()
        {

        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and i have database connected via EntityFramework and this is the generated class from EF

```
namespace mency
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class branch
    {
        public int Branch_ID { get; set; }
        public string Branch_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On my Page Code i have XAML

```
<Page x:Name="Departments_page" x:Class="mency.Department"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mency"
      xmlns:m="clr-namespace:mency.Models"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="502" d:DesignWidth="722"
      Title="Department" Initialized="Departments_page_Initialized" Loaded="Departments_page_Loaded">
    <Page.Resources>
        <m:Dep_class x:Key="dep_class" />

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="MediumAquamarine">

            <ComboBox x:Name="Branch_cbox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource dep_class}"  />



    </Grid>
```

how can i bind the combobox to the loaded results of my database.
this is my code behind the page :

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace mency
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Department.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Department : Page
    {
        medical_databaseEntitiescon _dbObj;


        public Department()
        {


            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Departments_page_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Departments_page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dbObj = new medical_databaseEntitiescon();
            //ComboBox = _dbObj.branches.ToList(); // I want combobox loaded with the results of this List
        }
    }
}
```

i am sorry for long question but i wish that someone help me

Comment: If you want to implement MVVM, I would suggest not to use code-behind. MVVM literally stands for Model-View-ViewModel, using code behind is against that framework. As for linking, if you really want to use code-behind, don't set `ItemSource={Binding ...` in your xaml, rather use `Branch_cbox.ItemsSource = *list from database*` inside the `Department()` constructor, and also set `DataContext = this;`.

Comment: ok but can you explain how to use it without codebehind plz ?

Comment: You should create medical_databaseEntitiescon object in model. In model write a method to return _dbObj.branches. In viewModel create an instance of your model. Also create a List<string> property in view model, in getter call the _dbObj.branches method of your model. Bind this List<string> to your combobox in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment I suggested not to use code-behind with an MVVM structure.

I'm sure you'll find tons of MVVM tutorials online, but I'll put a brief answer here.

First you need to create a class (ViewModel), name it anything, and set that as your DataContext so your View (the xaml) knows where to look for bindings, also change `ItemsSource="{StaticResource dep_class}"` to `ItemsSource="{Binding dep_class}"`.

```
<Page x:Name="Departments_page" x:Class="mency.Department"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mency"
  xmlns:m="clr-namespace:mency.Models"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="502" d:DesignWidth="722"
  Title="Department" Initialized="Departments_page_Initialized" Loaded="Departments_page_Loaded">
<Page.DataContext>
    <m:Dep_class *name of viewmodel class* />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="MediumAquamarine">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding dep_List}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDept, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

Then, in your class, you can create a list/collection called `dep_List` and a Dep_class variable called `SelectedDept`. Remember to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your viewmodel so that it can 'listen' and 'update' the view on changes. Finally, in your viewmodel you can fill `dep_List` with values from the database (if required use `DisplayMemberPath`). I know its a lot to take in, but once you learn, its very fun & powerful to use. I won't write your viewmodel code for you since that would be spoonfeeding, but instead, here are some helpful links:

[MVVM Creating the ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984438/mvvm-creating-the-viewmodel)

[Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) (a little hard to understand)

[The World's Simplest C# WPF MVVM Example](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project that heavily involves WPF data-binding with Entity Framework. The only way to take full advantage of the power data-binding gives you is to create wrapper classes that wrap your database objects. It's annoying but it's the only way to do it.

I have a base class called **ObservableObjectBase** that all my models (wrappers) implement that does all the Notify Property Change work for me and then make sure my MVVM framework uses it appropriately.

There is no set way to do this, but I will explain my solution briefly:

**Presenter (DAL)** - My presenter class handles all the reading and writing of data as well as transforming database objects by wrapping them. When data is written to the database this class is also responsible for transforming the wrappers back into data that makes sense for Entity Framework.

**Presentation Model (ViewModel)** - This stores all the wrapper objects and act as the DataContext for the UI - it does not keep references to any Entity Framework objects.

This is all a bit cumbersome for some and it would have been nice to bind straight to the database objects, but unfortunately that's just not a luxury that exists.